# If $X_n$ is a submartingale, and $M,N$ are stopping times with $M \leq N$, then $X_M \leq E(X_{N} \mid \mathcal{F}_M)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

I'm trying to show that if $X_n$ is a submartingale, with stopping times $M \leq N$, $P(N\leq k) =1$, then $E(X_{N} \mid \mathcal{F}_M) \geq X_M$.

The hint given is to use that, for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_M$,
$$K_A := \begin{cases}M&\text{on }A\\ N&\text{on }A^c \end{cases},$$
is a stopping time.

I was able to show that $K_A$ is indeed a stopping time, but I'm not sure how to proceed, or how to use this stopping time

Comment: Do you assume that $N$ is bounded?

Comment: Oops! Edited. Yes, I assume that $P(N\leq k) =1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Recall (or show) that $\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau}) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_{\sigma})$ for any bounded stopping times $\sigma \leq \tau$.
2. Apply Step 1 to the stopping times $\sigma = K_A$ (defined in your question) and $\tau=N$. Conclude that $$\mathbb{E}(X_N 1_A) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_M 1_A), \qquad A \in \mathcal{F}_M.$$
3. Using the definition of conditional expectation, show that $$\mathbb{E}(X_N 1_A) = \mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M) 1_A \big], \qquad A \in \mathcal{F}_M.$$
4. By Step 2 and 3,  it holds that $$\mathbb{E} \big[ \mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M) 1_A \big] \geq  \mathbb{E}(X_M 1_A)$$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_M$. Conclude that $\mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M) \geq X_M$. (Hint: Consider $A=\{\mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M)  < X_M\}$.)

Comment: What if $N$ is not bounded?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Well, then it doesn't work... but the OP just forgot to mention the assumption of boundedness, see the edited question.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the last step, so if we set $A = \{E(X_{N}| \mathcal{F}_{M}) < X_{M} \}$, we obtain $E[X_{M}1_{A}] \geq E[E(X_{N}|\mathcal{F}_{M})1_{A}]$ which should I guess give the equality  $E[X_{M}1_{A}] = E[E(X_{N}|\mathcal{F}_{M})1_{A}]$?

Comment: @user135520 We have $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[ (\mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M)-X_M) 1_A \bigg]=0.$$ Now set $Y :=  \mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M)-X_M$ and $A=\{\mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M)<X_M\}=\{Y<0\}$. From $$\mathbb{E}(Y 1_A) \geq 0$$ and $Y<0$ on $A$, it follows that $Y1_A=0$ a.s., i.e. $A$ is a null set. Hence, $\mathbb{E}(X_N \mid \mathcal{F}_M) \geq X_M$ a.s.